# C++0x atomic template implementation

Tags: c++, synchronization, c++11

I know that similar template exits in Intel's TBB, besides that I can't find any implementation on google or in Boost library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find discussions about this feature implementation in boost there : http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/11/144803.php

> > Can the N2427 - C++ Atomic Types and Operations be implemented
>
> > without the help of the compiler?
>
> No.
>
> They don't need to be intrinsics if you can write inline assembler  (or separately-compiled assembler for
> that matter) then you can write  the
> operations themselves directly. You
> might even be able to use  simple C++
> (e.g. just plain assignment for load
> or store).  The reason you need
> compiler support is preventing
> inappropriate  optimizations: atomic
> operations can't be optimized out, and
> generally  must not be reordered
> before or after any other operations.
> This means  that even non-atomic
> stores performed before an atomic
> store have to  be complete, and can't
> be cached in a register (for example).
> Also,  loads that occur after an
> atomic operation cannot be hoisted
> before  the atomic op.  On some
> compilers, just using inline assembler
> is enough. On others,  calling an
> external function is enough. MSVC
> provides
> _ReadWriteBarrier() to provide the compiler ordering. Other compilers
> need other flags.