# Why atomic_flag default constructor leaves state unspecified?

Tags: c++, constructor, atomic

When using [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag), one has to be careful to always explicitely initialize it using [`ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT), which is error-prone. However there is a default constructor... So, **is there an objective reason behind having a default constructor leaving the flag in an unspecifiate state ?**

Comment: AFAIK, the default constructor is guaranteed to initialize the variable with 0 but it is not specified whether 0 refers to “clear” or “set”. Of course, this raises more questions than it answers…

Comment: Sadly, this is not even the case, according to cppreference: *[ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT] is the only way to initialize std::atomic_flag to a definite value: the value held after any other initialization is unspecified.*. But I guess it is possible to see it your way...

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1379.htm

Comment: Typical ISO lossage, it can only ever arrive at consensus by making everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: @dyp That's a good source. I think the reasoning exposed here is broken, but it is perfectly acceptable as a answer to my question. If you post it I would upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1379.htm) (posted by [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) in comments), describes that this decision was made because on some architectures a zero-initialized `atomic_flag` would correspond to a set state, and on some it would correspond to a cleared state. Because of this, it was defined that an `atomic_flag` that is not explicitly initialized with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is initially in an indeterminate state.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered by **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885300/2261538)**

I had this issue come up with a map that contained a tuple that contained an `std::atomic_flag` - and putting in explicit initalization easily adds a lot of complicated code.

A *workaround* solution is to just wrap it in another type, such as this:

```
struct atomic_flag_ : public std::atomic_flag {

    atomic_flag_() : std::atomic_flag{ ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT } {
    }

};
```

*or without inheritance:*

```
struct atomic_flag_ {

    std::atomic_flag flag{ ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT };

};
```

Now you don't have to worry about initalization (except in some special corner cases, like `static` init *fiasco*).

Comment: It might be better idea to use `std::atomic_bool`, since in practice it would be lock free as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106936/are-atomic-variables-lock-free